# Hevajra & Nairātmyā are Lord Siva & Ma Parvati respectively?

Tags: shiva, parvati, buddhism

Three major branches of Buddhism along with their percentage of practitioners are

1. Mayāyāna - 53.2%
2. Theravad - 35.8%
3. Vajrayana - 5.7%

My interest is [Vajrayana](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vajrayana) here. As you can see through the link, it is Tantrik tradition of Buddhism. Moreover, it is highly related to Shaivism (according to the link ).

Now Hevajra is considered to be the first enlightened being in Vajrayana. Some of the characteristics of **Hevajra** are happened to be as follows-

- He is dark blue in color.
- He appears from a syllable Hum which is appeared on a lotus. ( NOTE- Hum is pranava for Lord Shiva )
- Each face of Hevajra has 3 eyes.
- He is wrathful yet compassionate.
- He dances with his consort Nairātmyā in ecstasy.
- He has skulls with him.

At other places we found Hevajra is accompanied with 8 more females which are his consorts. Their name are as follows -

1. **Gauri** , holding a moon.
2. Cauri, holding a sun vessel.
3. **Vetaali**, holding a pure water.
4. Ghasmari, holding a medicine.
5. Pukashi, holding a vajra.
6. Savari, holding ambrosia.
7. **Chandali**, holding a drum.
8. Dombi, With hands dancing.

So, my question is basically whether there are any texts in Scriptures or Tantra ( Buddhist or Hindu ) which can be taken as sufficient to claim Hevajra & Nairātmyā as Lord Shiva & mother Parvati respectively. 
[image: Hevajra]

Comment: You can provide some info about Hevajra and Nairatma in your question. Most of the people may not know them.

Comment: Yes, gonna put details soon .

Comment: its well known in tantra sect about similarities between hindu, buddhist and jina tantras (agamas).